# Avoid Gitlab-CI build for develop branch on finish release (git-flow)

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, git-flow

We are using Git-Flow with automatic builds and releases using Gitlab-CI.

Every commit on the `develop` branch triggers the build stage.

Every commit on the `master` branch triggers first the build stage and then the `release` stage (which uses the artifacts from the build stage).

This works fine, there is only one drawback for which I couldn't find a solution:

Whenever we finish a release in the git repository, this means commits on both `develop` and `master` branch. That also triggers the build stage on both branches, building from the exact same source versions (at this point there are two different commits that contain the exact same code).

I would like to avoid the build on the development branch, but only in this special case.

I don't think this is possible using the logic inside `.gitlab-ci.yml`, but that's ok. I would be glad if I could recognize this situation and end the build script early.

I think this means the following conditions have all to be met:

- We are on the `develop` branch. (simple)
- The current commit was merged from both `master` and `develop`.
- The merged `master` commit has a tag attached to it.

What git magic could I do to recognize if this is the case for a certain commit in the `develop` branch?

I am using Python for this, but I would appreciate helpful answers in any programming language :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use `only` in gitlab-ci.yml

```
deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy-dev
  script:
    -  ./somescript.sh
  only:
    refs:
      - develop

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy-prod
  script:
    -  ./somescript.sh
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - tags
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not really solve my problem. 
In general I want to do the same build on develop commits and master branches / tags.  I just don't want the build to run  on a develop commit that results from a Git Flow "finish release" action. That means it isn't enough to look at the current branch, it's ancestors have to be taken into account as well.
I don't think this is possible using `.gitlab-ci.yml` - but I'd love to be wrong here :-)